# Is there a way to use *some* packages from upcoming version of Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, ppa

For my work I need to stay close to 2.8 version of llvm (not yet released). I found out that Maverick will have it installed and already have some prepackaged version.

Is there a way I can use just this packages (and all the packages it depends on) in my current Ubuntu installation? Some kind of repository maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think too many people are going to get enthusiastic about packaging it until it nears its release. That's still the best part of a month away. All the llvm ppas

In the meanwhile, you *might* be able to just pull in the [`llvm-2.8` packages from Maverick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=llvm-2.8). I say "*might*" because it just doesn't work all the time. Sometimes the dependencies run too deep and you end up pulling in so much of Maverick things become unstable.

Otherwise you're left with compiling it yourself. That should be well within your abilities but generally speaking, this could upset anything that depends on `llvm`. I think as it is, nothing in Lucid depends on `llvm` (it's not installed here) so you might be fine.

If you are going to compile, the [Getting Started with the LLVM System](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) is going to be your main reference for the next few hours.

Another option is developing against Lucid's 2.7 and testing on a Maverick install. The most convenient way for a sole-developer would be through a virtual machine (ie VirtualBox). This is extra-handy as you'll be in a good position to file bugs where they need filing so you're not left with a buggy environment when you do upgrade your dev machine to Maverick.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use LLVM from a ppa packaged for you version (lucid?). You can search PPAs at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas .
If you can't find it in a ppa, you can try just downloading and installing the maverick package(s) and if they don't have many dependencies (or the versions of the dependencies are the same in lucid and maverick) there's a good chance that it'll work. Note that this is not recommended, though.

Answer (score 0):

I [don't see any](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=llvm&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) prepackaged setups for it, for the latest version you would need to compile it yourself. the [getting started](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) guide explains getting the source, setting up your environment and building the suite.

The first 3 points in the guide cheekily starts off with

> 1. Read the documentation.
> 2. Read the documentation.
> 3. Remember that you were warned twice about reading the documentation.